# I don' t find this symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I need this symbol and I don' t find it.

I need the : t

Only I find the `$\tau$` but it is not

Can you help me?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: almost certainly `\mathcal{T}`.

Comment: I can almost surely say it is `mathcal T`, like @Barbara Beeton;